# Wordpress: Removing the last comma for tag list

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

I've created a custom foreach output that helps give me a tag id per post. I'm using commas to separate each tag. However, the last tag outputs a comma too, like this:

kittens, dogs, parrots, (<-- last comma)

How should I go about revising the foreach output so that the last comma is removed so it displays like this:

kittens, dogs, parrots

Here's the code:

```
<?php
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
    foreach($posttags as $tag) {
        echo '<a href="';
        echo bloginfo(url);
        echo '/?tag=' . $tag->slug . '" class="tag-link-' . $tag->term_id . '">' . $tag->name . '</a>, ';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Is nobody but Jan Fabry even going to bother properly indenting their answers if not the question's original code? (I've taken the courtesy to do the indenting now.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this?

```
<?php
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
    $loop = 1; // *
    foreach($posttags as $tag) {
        echo '<a href="';
        echo bloginfo(url);
        if ($loop<count($posttags)) $endline = ', '; else $endline = ''; // *
        $loop++ // *
        echo '/?tag=' . $tag->slug . '" class="tag-link-' . $tag->term_id . '">' . $tag->name . '</a>' . $endline;
    }
}
?>
```

**edit** or

```
<?php
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
    $tagstr = '';
    foreach($posttags as $tag) {
        $tagstr .= '<a href="';
        $tagstr .= bloginfo(url);
        $tagstr .= '/?tag=' . $tag->slug . '" class="tag-link-' . $tag->term_id . '">' . $tag->name . '</a>';
    }
    $tagstr = substr($tagstr , 0, -2);
    echo $tagstr ;
}
?>
```

Comment: It's the longer code of all the suggestions, but it's the one I understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[`implode`](http://php.net/implode) is your friend, if you don't want to be [Shlemiel the painter](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html).

```
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
   $tagstrings = array();
   foreach($posttags as $tag) {
      $tagstrings[] = '<a href="' . get_tag_link($tag->term_id) . '" class="tag-link-' . $tag->term_id . '">' . $tag->name . '</a>';
   }
   echo implode(', ', $tagstrings);
}

// For an extra touch, use this function instead of `implode` to a better formatted string
// It will return "A, B and C" instead of "A, B, C"
function array_to_string($array, $glue = ', ', $final_glue = ' and ') {
    if (1 == count($array)) {
        return $array[0];
    }
    $last_item = array_pop($array);
    return implode($glue, $array) . $final_glue . $last_item;
}
```

Comment: This outputs the the blog's url several times before it gives the tag information correctly. Still a good function to know! Thank you!

Comment: @bookmark: I updated my example to use [`get_tag_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tag_link) instead of constructing the link myself, this will always use the correct format. And I added a "bonus" function that I used before, to get nicer output.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with [rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php).

```
<?php
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
    foreach($posttags as $tag) {
        $output.='<a href="';
        $output.= bloginfo(url);
        $output.= '/?tag=' . $tag->slug . '" class="tag-link-' . $tag->term_id . '">' . $tag->name . '</a>, ';
    }
    echo rtrim($output, ', ');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing commas in Wordpress version 6.2.2 has become easier than ever. I tried all the listed solutions above but none doesn't work for my problem. so I have to share the simplest solution found.

Edit your single-post template to the following

**Before**

```
<?php if ( is_single() ) {
            echo get_the_tag_list( sprintf('<footer class="entry-meta"><span class="tag-links"><span class="label">%s:</span> ', esc_html__('Tags', 'newscard') ), ', ', '</span><!-- .tag-links --></footer><!-- .entry-meta -->' );
        }
         wp_link_pages( array(
            'before'            => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages: ', 'newscard' ),
            'separator'         => '',
            'link_before'       => '<span>',
            'link_after'        => '</span>',
            'after'             => '</div>'
        ) ); ?>
```

**After**

```
<?php if ( is_single() ) {
            echo get_the_tag_list( sprintf('<footer class="entry-meta"><span class="tag-links"><span class="label">%s:</span> ', esc_html__('Tags', 'newscard') ), ' ', '</span><!-- .tag-links --></footer><!-- .entry-meta -->' );
        }
         wp_link_pages( array(
            'before'            => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages: ', 'newscard' ),
            'separator'         => '',
            'link_before'       => '<span>',
            'link_after'        => '</span>',
            'after'             => '</div>'
        ) ); ?>
```

Comment once you spot the change. I hope this works for you too.